# Take User to Background Refresh Settings programmatically in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, xcode5, application-settings

In my app I am checking Background Refresh Settings is enabled or not. If not enabled i want that app will open the Setting option and take user to Background Refresh options. 
Is it possible to do programmatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to do something like that ?

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundRefreshStatus] == UIBackgroundRefreshStatusAvailable) {

    NSLog(@"Background updates are available for the app.");
}else if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundRefreshStatus] == UIBackgroundRefreshStatusDenied)
{
    NSLog(@"The user explicitly disabled background behavior for this app or for the whole system.");
}else if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundRefreshStatus] == UIBackgroundRefreshStatusRestricted)
{
    NSLog(@"Background updates are unavailable and the user cannot enable them again. For example, this status can occur when parental controls are in effect for the current user.");
}
```